# Access the same method of an sdk from different locations

Tags: java, android

I need some help with Java/Android code. I have a piece of hardware that I am accessing over USB on Android. The SDK has certain calls which I override in my code to receive data. An example of this call is shown below.

```
@Override
    public void deviceFingerCountChanged(final IBScanDevice device, final FingerCountState fingerState) 
    {
        /* TODO: UPDATE DESCRIPTION OF FINGER COUNT */
        switch (fingerState)
        {
            default:
            case FINGER_COUNT_OK:
                setStatus("capturing");
                break;
            case TOO_MANY_FINGERS:
                setStatus("too many fingers");
                break;
            case TOO_FEW_FINGERS:
                setStatus("too few fingers");
                break;
            case NON_FINGER:
                setStatus("non-finger");
                break;
        }
    }
```

This function as I said exists in the SDK and I am simply overriding it to be able to capture the data that it returns once I make a call to the SDK. The problem is that this currently only caters for a single hardware device to access the SDK, but I want to do this for two devices. So currently when I use the two devices they both come into this same function when the SDK returns data, I want this to go to two different instances of this function so that I can split the data that is being returned by the SDK.

So what I am trying to figure out is how I would allow this to work for two different instances, is there a way to create this function twice in two different classes and then access them independently? Perhaps use threads somehow to do this? I am really not sure how to do this and don't really know what to search for on the internet to find a way to do this?

Comment: I am not sure but what i think you can do that based on the IBScanDevice device, this argument must refer to the device which send this callback. on the basis of this you can distinguish which device send data.

Comment: @theJango this is just an example of one of the callback methods, the rest do not all have the device parameter. So they are not able to distinguish from where the data came.